# Variant Spellcasting for Warlocks

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, balance, house-rules, warlock

I was looking at the Warlock in 5e and wondered: what would it be like if they were a 'full caster'?  The idea I had would be that their cantrips and spells known would remain the same, as well as the spell list they learn from.  The only difference(s) would be that they would have spell slots in the same way that the cleric, druid, sorcerer, or wizard do, and would regain spent spell slots after a long rest.  Could more experienced DMs or Homebrewers explain how this would be a good, functional, or even bad idea?

P.S. I'm aware that Mystic Arcanum and/or Eldritch Master might have to be altered (in the case of the latter it could just be an even better capstone for this variant Warlock).

Thanks for any replies/input!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. As currently written, this seems more like a somewhat broad discussion prompt than a clear, answerable question, and would probably be more suitable for a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). However, if you specify your goals/parameters more clearly (e.g. you want to check if it's balanced), it might be possible to give a "best" answer to the question. Note that "idea generation" aspects of the question might need to be removed.

Comment: I there any particular goal, you would be trying to achieve with this? How would they choose which spells they can cast? As wizards do? As clerics?

Comment: To V2Blast: Sorry! I'm new to this site, and I didn't know exactly where best to post this.  I would love to know if it would be balanced or not, and if it wasn't, what steps one might take to so so.  Should I go ahead and rephrase the post according to your suggestions?

Comment: To J.E.: I have never played Warlock and was just curious as to how it would affect gameplay going from a short-rest caster to a long-rest caster.  As for the spells they can cast, I imagine it would work much the same as the Warlock normally does: learning spells and cantrips from the Warlock spell list.

Comment: This question seems to fall very close to "you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question", which is on the list of things to avoid asking. This site isn't a very good format for questions like that.

Comment: Well, do you have some recommended sites or forums that might be better suited for this post?

Comment: @Bullbo92: See the Q&A on the meta site linked in my earlier comment.